# Interaction of Web User Controls and Structure (Having conceptual difficulties)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp .net C# project I have a page defualt.aspx on which I have placed 2 components.
So in all I have:

```
1) default.aspx (main page, not doing much code in it)
2) wuc_Lookup.ascx (doing a lot here, grabbing data, setting session, etc)
3) wuc_PageMessages.ascx (has a couple of panels and labels for message output
```

)

The intent is to use 3) in any page in my application.  1) and 2) are already working. My issue is that the Page_Load sequence is:

1st default Loads
2nd wuc_pageMessage loads
3rd wuc_lookup loads

The problem with this is that The wuc_pageMessage is relevant only ***after*** wuc_lookup runs.

My intent was not to put code in Page_Load for the message wuc_pageMessage control because I wanted to be able to call a method to post the message during the component load of wuc_lookup.  I do this because only after wuc_lookup do I set the session which I use for the message value.

I actually got values showing up if I put the code in wuc_lookup to manipulate the code-in-front server control (panels and labels) using this.parent.findControl syntax...

But then when I try to rip that code and put it into the code-behind for wuc_pageMessage, and then call the method from the wuc_lookup it has fallen out of scope or context...

So I tried to change this.Parent by passing httpContext.current.handler as casting it as page...that didn't work...then I tried passing Object sender from the calling component...that didn't work either.  Neither of them had the Parent property and or it was null which led me to believe that once the wuc_PageMessages.ascx loaded it was a dead deal until a repost happens and that is ugly and something I don't want to do.

I am having some implementation issues and I am not sure what to do.  I have been stunk on this for eight hours and Is there just something I am not seeing?

I want to keep away from spagetti code.  I don't want to have to scatter code-behind in 3 different  files.  Theoretically I should only need 2 of these to talk to eachother.  i don't want code-behind in default..it's basically just a container.  I want to trigger the wuc_pageMessage from wuc_Lookup.ascx without having it be  "in" wuc_Lookup.ascx (peer web user controls)  I want that to always be a peer relationship. Any advice would be great ...thanks...

Comment: You could wrap your user control with an updatepanel, so you could only refresh that part ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the wuc_PageMessages logic from the page_load to the page_prerender event.

Comment: But what about the reference?  For example when I take the code into the component itself httpContext.current as Page was not working, nor was the reference to sender.  I'm looking for a way or syntax of how to find the controls once they are in the code behind of the component itself this.parent.findcontrol worked in the external component, but once the component has gone out of scope I'm trying to understand what to pass into the external function that replaces this.Parent...I'm at a loss with that one... or will I not be able to invoke a function in another control without a delegate?

Comment: This was exactly right.  I fiddled around with this a while and realized I had forgotten to check a very important thing.  Once I put the call to the component from OnPreRender overridden event(using it's name from the code in front...I was able to access everything and it worked great.  It was not out of scope any longer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the preRender you would do it on the default.aspx preRender because this event fires after the wuc_lookup.  Prerender will not fire on the components for some reason.  So yes, this only solves part of the issue.  I am not sure how you would get the alreeady loaded component of wuc_PageMessages to get back into scope.  If you try to reference components on a component that has already loaded, you will get a null, like they are not there or not in scope anymore... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I did put the call to the components method on the OnPreRendr overridden method in the default.asp in which the component was registered in the code-front.  Any page that I use that component on, I would place it a call to it's method in the OnPreRender method of the parent page.